# Generic reverse tunnel

Tags: tunneling

I am searching for a generic reverse tunnel application. Here is what I have in mind: It would consist of an inside (behind nat) and outside part. The "inside" part would try to establish a connection to the "outside" part automatically. The "outside" part could accept connetions and since it has a connection to "inside" it could tunnel all the communication to the "inside" part which in turn could connect to any server behind the nat.

This seems to be such a simple concept, is there an app doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for vpn possibly, more specifically a TAP vpn.  OpenVPN can do this.

If you only have a few ports you want to forward, ssh works as well with the -R flag and the gateway ports option set.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a VPN to me. Try OpenVPN http://www.openvpn.net/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is ssh. Check this [link](http://www.szarp.com.pl/howto/howto/html/ssh.html). It's in Polish but you can translate it using [Google Translate](http://www.google.com/translate).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different things on the "outside" and the "inside", then OpenVPN is a good method for gluing the two together.

If you are just port-forwarding, you might just investigate port-forwarding on whatever firewall device is between you and the internet.